# admin-ajax.php & my wp-admin folder url showing in header

Tags: functions, ajax, wp-admin, javascript

Im currently using this script 
https://github.com/JonMasterson/WordPress-Post-Like-System/blob/master/post-like.php

It works fine except the url of admin-ajax.php which has the url of my wp-admin folder too appears on my site's header.
These codes:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var simpleLikes = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/aw\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","like":"Favorite","unlike":"Remove Favorite"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

How can i fix it? i mean so that codes won't show up on my site's header cause it pretty much revealing and i dont want others to know where my admin folder is located..

Comment: Have you check what is the <title> value in your HTML code?

Comment: Yes the title is fine too, <title> MyMovies</title>

Comment: Sorry for asking but to clarify your site header you mean the title that is being shown in the tab of the browser right?

Comment: This is completely normal and no reason to worry. Your admin directory is not a secret, and it can be "found out" by many other ways.

Comment: Oh I see you mean the html header, sorry my mistake. I misunderstood what you meant as header. Yes as toscho said is completely normal.

Comment: yes but im planning to change my site's admin directory soon 'cause i'm getting too much login attemps. Are there any other way to hide it so that it won't appear on my site's html header?

Comment: You can limit the number of login attempts using a plugin. What you are going to do is security through obscurity and is not a good option.